# 古典日本語について：「つ」で二つの名詞を連接する

Tags: grammar, particles, classical-japanese

最近Bilibiliで（実質的に中国版のニコニコ動画サイト）見つけたのは、[文語版深海少女](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1Sq4y1P7DY)の動画です。

誰かがあのめっちゃ流行ってた曲「深海少女」の歌詞を古典日本語（文語）に変換し、動画を作り出しました。歌詞を見習う時、気になったのは最後の部分の一言です：

元の歌詞：

> 深海少女 腕を引かれる 歌う祝福の**マリンスノー** 
> 深海少女 もっと知りたい 心惹かれるあの人を見つけたから

この動画：

> 深海少女　腕を引かるる　歌ふ　幸{さち}なる**海{うみ}つ雪{ゆき}** 
> 深海少女　知りたけれども　心[魅]{ひ}かるる見つけつる彼{あ}が為{ため}

この作詞者は日本人のようですのに、古典日本語の知識をあんまり持ってなく、この歌詞が正しい文語か正しくないか知り得ません。正確だったら、なぜ現代語の「マリンスノー」を文語にするとき、「海」と「雪」の中に「つ」が入ってますか。「海つ雪」そのものを調べったりしても結果は見つかりませんでした。この「つ」は古典文法によって大事なのか、そして、なんのためにあるか教えてほしいです。

※ 音声によってこの「つ」は促音ではありません。はっきりと発音されています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

つ is an ancient version of の, and it is occasionally used for archaism. In modern works, you may see:

- [[外つ国]{とつくに}](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A4%96%E3%81%A4%E5%9B%BD/)
- [中つ【なかつ】](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%A4/), 下つ【しもつ】

まつげ is also etymologically 目【ま】+つ+毛, or 目の毛. See [this dictionary definition](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A4#:%7E:text=%E3%80%8A%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A%E3%80%8B%E4%BD%93%E8%A8%80%E3%82%84%E5%BD%A2%E5%AE%B9%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE,%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82).

So 海つ雪 can be interpreted as 海の雪, although it is unlikely that the phrase was actually used in the past.

Comment: ありがとうございました！勉強になります

Comment: How would you rate the quality of this Classical Japanese "translation"? I don't know if you had seen the video, but even just based on the two line I pasted above, would you say this Classical Japanese is the "real" kind? Or it feels somewhat off?

Comment: @dvx2718 It feels somewhat puzzling to me (why るる and ども?) but my knowledge of 古文 is quite limited, so I may be wrong.